# sql - sum() function not working as I expect it

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum

I have this query:

```
SELECT
    gs.x AS metric
    , SUM(p.cnt) as values
FROM
    generate_series(0,200,1) as gs(x) 
    LEFT JOIN polutiondistributionstatistic p
        ON gs.x = (p.polutionmm2 / 100)
    LEFT JOIN crates                        AS c
        ON p.crateid = c.id
    LEFT JOIN lines                         AS l
        ON l.id = p.lineid
    LEFT JOIN powervisions                  AS pv
        ON pv.id = l.powervisionid
           AND p.crateid = c.id
           AND p.lineid = l.id
           AND l.powervisionid = pv.id
           AND pv.name IN ('PV101')
           AND p.areaname = 'outside'
           AND c.name IN ('13', '24603')
           AND to_timestamp(p.startts) >= '2021-01-26T13:29:01.632Z'
           AND to_timestamp(p.stopts) <= '2021-02-02T13:29:01.632Z'
GROUP BY
    metric
ORDER BY
    metric ASC
```

the query returns these values:

[image]

If I replace 'PV101' with "XXXXX" I would expect it to return still all 200 rows, and that the values column has all "0" or null since XXXXX does not exist inside the table. Instead, it returns the exact same values as with PV101. same for all the other conditions. no matter what I change, it returns always the same number in the values column.

Why?

Comment: what about puting your name part into a where clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are joining to `p` before you join to `pv`.  That means that the filtering on the *later* table doesn't work.

So, I think you want the `from` clause to look like:

```
from generate_series(0,200,1) gs(x) left join
     (polutiondistributionstatistic p join
      crates c
      on p.crateid = c.id join
      lines l 
      on l.id = p.lineid join
      powervisions pv
      on pv.id = l.powervisionid
     )
     on gs.x = (p.polutionmm2/100) and
        . . .
```

Comment: thank you, unfortunately it returns null on every row with this change...

Comment: nevermind found it... my wrogn.. thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Because you are taking the sum of the `p.cnt` and what matters is only one table for you `polutiondistributionstatistic`.

Your query will not give different result for different values of the `pv.name` as it is left joined(condition is in the `ON` clause) and not considered in sum.

What matters in the query is only following portion.

```
select 
gs.x as metric,
sum(p.cnt) as values
from generate_series(0,200,1) as gs(x) 
left join polutiondistributionstatistic p on gs.x = (p.polutionmm2/100)
```

All other left joined tables will not impact the result (even if there is one to many mapping then also your result will be multiplied by some n number where n is 1-n mapping between tables)

One thing you can do is to use sub-query as follows:

```
select gs.x as metric,
       sum(p.cnt) as values
  from generate_series(0,200,1) as gs(x) 

left join 
 (select p.cnt, (p.polutionmm2/100) as x
from polutiondistributionstatistic p
join crates as c on p.crateid = c.id
join lines as l on l.id = p.lineid
join powervisions as pv on pv.id = l.powervisionid
and p.crateid = c.id 
and p.lineid = l.id 
and l.powervisionid = pv.id
and pv.name in ('PV101')  
and p.areaname = 'outside'
and c.name in ('13','24603')
and to_timestamp(p.startts) >= '2021-01-26T13:29:01.632Z' 
and to_timestamp(p.stopts) <= '2021-02-02T13:29:01.632Z') p on p.x = gs.x
group by metric order by metric asc
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the filtering not on the retrieved rows but before that. You can try removing it from the `where` clause and move it to `left join` clause of `powervisions` table.

```
select 
gs.x as metric,
sum(p.cnt) as values
from generate_series(0,200,1) as gs(x) 
left join polutiondistributionstatistic p on gs.x = (p.polutionmm2/100)
left join crates as c on p.crateid = c.id
left join lines as l on l.id = p.lineid
left join powervisions as pv on (pv.id = l.powervisionid and pv.name in ('PV101')) 
and p.crateid = c.id 
and p.lineid = l.id 
and l.powervisionid = pv.id 
and p.areaname = 'outside'
and c.name in ('13','24603')
and to_timestamp(p.startts) >= '2021-01-26T13:29:01.632Z' 
and to_timestamp(p.stopts) <= '2021-02-02T13:29:01.632Z'
group by metric order by metric asc
```